# mocking in multithreaded context

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, mocking

I would like to write some integration tests for some classes that start in multithreaded context. The problem is one of the classes has some external library which I want to mock.

Example:

Foo.py

```
import threading

from external_lib import function_i_want_to_mock


class Foo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print(self.run_function())

    def run_function(self):
        return function_i_want_to_mock()
```

Bar.py

```
import threading

from foo import Foo


class Bar(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.start()
```

test_mock_thread.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from bar import Bar


def test_run():
    with patch("foo.function_i_want_to_mock"):
        bar = Bar()
        bar.start()
        bar.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

When I run this test, the function does not get mocked and it is being imported normally. Is there a way to pass the mocked version through the threads?